# Does commoncrawl contain only benign URLs? If yes, how they avoid indexing malicious URLs?

Tags: url, phishing, common-crawl

We would like to know whether commoncrawl database can be used as legitimate dataset for URL classification.

Comment: We're all left guessing what you mean by "legitimate dataset" -- every sample of URLs has selection effects.

Answer (score 3):

The Common Crawl archives may include all kinds of malicious content at a low rate. At present, only link spam is classified and partially blocked from being crawled.

In general, a broad sample web crawl may include spam, malicious sites etc. The Common Crawl archives are also used for research on web security, cf.
  https://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=commoncrawl+vulnerability

This topic has already been discussed on https://groups.google.com/d/msg/common-crawl/xmSZX85cRjg/zwi5vn4NBAAJ